# On click display and update data-attribute in another div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, custom-data-attribute

I have a quiz and on clicking an answer (button/link). I'd like the give feedback as to as to whether the answer was correct or incorrect.

I thought using `data-` might be the best way to do this but I suppose I could have several paragraphs hidden and just show the one linked to the button when clicked.

What are peoples thoughts on that? Is the length of text a problem with `data-` as I've never used it in this way/with this volume of copy?

It would be nice if when the content was added/changed the container transitioned in vertical height and the updated text faded in. So the approach might be dictated by that.

Be good to get peoples feedback on the best approach for this.

```css
.btn {display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 24px;}
.feedback { background: #f7f7f7; padding: 24px; }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn" data-value="false" data-feedback="That's incorrect lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua">Option 1</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" data-value="true" data-feedback="That's correct! Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.">Option 2</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" data-value="false" data-feedback="Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur">Option 3</a>

<div class="feedback">
  <p>[ FEEDBACK APPEARS HERE ]</p>
</div>
```

Comment: All it takes is for one participant to take a look at developer console to see all the correct answers right there :) Instead your server should receive the answer and determine if it's correct or not... But that's another story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const feedbackButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.quiz [data-feedback]');

for (let i = 0; i < feedbackButtons.length; i++) {
  feedbackButtons[i].onclick = function() {
    const feedbackElement = this.parentNode.querySelector('.feedback');
    
    feedbackElement.querySelector('p').innerHTML = this.dataset.feedback;
    
    if (this.dataset.value === 'true') {
      feedbackElement.classList.remove('incorrect');
      feedbackElement.classList.add('correct');
    } else if (this.dataset.value === 'false') {
      feedbackElement.classList.remove('correct');
      feedbackElement.classList.add('incorrect');
    }
    
    feedbackElement.style.transition = 'none';
    feedbackElement.classList.remove('active');
    setTimeout(() => {
      feedbackElement.removeAttribute('style');
      feedbackElement.classList.add('active');
    });
  };
}
```

```css
.feedback {
  height: 0;
  transition: height 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.feedback.active {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 60px;
}

.feedback.correct {
  background-color: #00FF00;
}

.feedback.incorrect {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="quiz">
  <a href="#" class="btn" data-value="false" data-feedback="That's incorrect lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua">Option 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn" data-value="true" data-feedback="That's correct! Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.">Option 2</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn" data-value="false" data-feedback="Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur">Option 3</a>

  <div class="feedback">
    <p>[ FEEDBACK APPEARS HERE ]</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I was just thinking about when it appears, animating the height of the div ...that's gonna be pretty difficult isn't it. Going from an empty div with unspecified height to then content just appearing. So I might need to have a height set on the div?

Comment: It's possible but the height needs to be a fixed number. For example, now I have set it to 60 pixels.

Comment: Yeah I thought so, can't transition from auto to value etc thanks

Comment: Actually, just seen you updated with some classes to style/transition. I guess I could use the same code to toggle a class of true/false depending on which button is clicked, which could be useful as well

Comment: One oversight I made, as the quizzes open in a popup. Is there could be a couple of these on a page. Is there away, if each group of buttons was within a `.quiz` wrapper. The feedback could only be applied to the div within that instance/container? Just so text wasn't added to a div you're not viewing?

Comment: Yes it sounds good. I will edit the snippet tomorrow if you like.

Comment: That'd be a big help, I tried having a lot around with it. I know in jQuery I can target the child but less sure with vanilla JS!

Comment: I made some changes to the snippet. If you need something more specific about the wrapper of the quiz feel free to ask me.

Comment: Thanks @kostas that's great! The only question I have is about the 'style', is that needed? It doesn't look like it's used? I wonder if I could swap it so it has the class of the `data-value` as well, so text is green or red depending on answer?

Comment: I updated the script to use ````data-value```` now and add the proper class to the feedback container.

Comment: I updated the markup for styling the questions which broke the JS. I think I've got it working again by added another `.parentNode` to `.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector(".quiz__feedback");` is the the correct way to go about this? Assuming it needed to 'go up' two steps now? https://codepen.io/moy/pen/oNqRjmO

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't like the approach of inserting the feedback on the element property. It's a leap that your user might check the console, but someone definitely could. I would rather store those feedbacks and get them back with the button index or something like that.

```js
const feedbacks = [
  "That's incorrect lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua",
  "That's correct! Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.",
  "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur"
]

function getFeedback(bntIndex) {
  document.getElementById("feedbackText").innerText = feedbacks[bntIndex]
  document.getElementById("feedbackContainer").classList.add("visible")
  document.getElementById("feedbackContainer").classList.remove("hidden")
}
```

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.feedback {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  transition: 1s linear;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.feedback p {
  padding: 20px;
  transition: 5s linear;
}

.hidden {
  height: 0;
}

.visible {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn" data-value="false" onclick="getFeedback(0)">Option 1</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" data-value="true" onclick="getFeedback(1)">Option 2</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" data-value="false" onclick="getFeedback(2)">Option 3</a>

<div id="feedbackContainer" class="feedback hidden">
  <p id="feedbackText">Feedback</p>
</div>
```

EDIT: I inserted a snippet for the transition behavior you wanted. Hope its what you are looking for :)

Comment: Yeah I agree with having stuff on the page but it might be ok in this instance due to how the html is 'launched' as it's not a webpage. Quite a lot of 'quizzes' too throughout many pages so be easier than updating JS with it all ...hopefully!

Answer (score 0):

**It's just 2 line code Try this,**

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
  var current_feedback = $(this).attr('data-feedback');
  $(".feedback>p").html(current_feedback);
});
```

***Here is full example.***

```js
$(".btn").click(function(){
  var current_feedback = $(this).attr('data-feedback');
  $(".feedback>p").html(current_feedback);
});
```

```css
.btn {display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 24px;}
.feedback { background: #f7f7f7; padding: 24px; }
.bg-success{background:#11aa88;}
.bg-warning{background:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <a href="#" class="btn" data-value="false" data-feedback="That's incorrect lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua">Option 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-value="true" data-feedback="That's correct! Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.">Option 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-value="false" data-feedback="Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur">Option 3</a>

  <div class="feedback">
    <p>[ FEEDBACK APPEARS HERE ]</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the `data-value` as a class as well using the same method? So depending on what's clicked you can add true or false. To be able to style differently? Just wondering - thanks! :D

Comment: @user1406440 , yes, you can add any attribute and get detail not only `data-*` . anything you can access

Comment: For for the late reply one this. I got this nearly working by setting `var current_status = $(this).attr('data-value');` then adding a class to the wrapper with `$(".feedback").addClass(current_status);` ...but if you click 2 buttons and the `data-value` is different it adds both classes at the same time - any ideas?

Comment: Might be easier to see on this actually: https://codepen.io/moy/pen/LYdoEBG - also now I have multiple quiz questions - I wondered how I could just target the child/relevant feedback block on click?

Comment: @user1406440 , I saw your link, you can first remove both class `true` and `false` on very first. `$(".quiz__feedback").removeClass('true'); $(".quiz__feedback").removeClass('false');` then do addClass. This will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! The only issue now is only showing the feedback for the question/button you've click. Currently if you click a button and there are 3 questions, the same feedback is added to all of them. So I somehow need to only target the button/feedback within the same div?

Comment: Actually think I've resolved by adding everything to a single string like this `$(this).parents(".quiz__item").find(".quiz__feedback p").html(current_feedback).removeClass("true false").addClass(current_value);` :)

Comment: this will cause issue, Let do first click on false anser then true answer, then this condition will not work, telling you why, becuase you'd used `removeClass("true false")` . it will not check `removeClass("false true")`

Comment: Seems to work ok for me? If I click around in any order there aren't problems? I'm lead to believe that it will just remove either of those classes if they exist? Then add a new one? I am a total jQuery noob though!

Comment: yes, you need to remove first then addclass that will not make any kind of issue.